# ある範囲で広義単調増加する数列を列挙する

Tags: python, python3, アルゴリズム

次の条件を満たす数列を列挙する方法はありますか．

- 長さがNの正整数列
- 1 <= A_1 <= A_2 <= ... <= A_N <= M
- 1 <= N, M <= 10

再帰関数を用いることにより目的は一先ず達成出来ましたが，配列のコピーのためパフォーマンスは悪いものと想像します．

```py
N = 2
M = 3

a = [0] * N
def dfs(pre_a, depth):
    if depth == N:
        pool.append(a.copy())
        return
    for i in range(pre_a, M + 1):
        a[depth] = i
        dfs(i, depth + 1)

pool = []
dfs(1, 0)
pool  # [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
```

`itertools`等を用いてスマートに書く方法が御座いましたらご教示下さい．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)を使いましょう。

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

N = 2
M = 3

print(list(combinations_with_replacement(range(1, M + 1), N)))
#[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

各要素をタプルではなくリストにしたいなら、`map(list, ...)`で囲みましょう。

```py
print(list(map(list, combinations_with_replacement(range(1, M + 1), N))))
#[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
```